# R: Minimum and maximum values by row with unknown number of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

For a data frame, I need to find the minimum and maximum values, by row, for an unknown number of columns from column 2 onwards. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# test data
(test_data <- tibble(id = c(1:9), 
                     x = runif(9), 
                     x2 = runif(9),
                     x3 = runif(9)))
samples = 100    

# This example, which specifies the column names, correctly finds the min and max values by row
(test_1 <- test_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min_val = min(x, x2, x3), max_val = max(x, x2, x3)))

# This example does not
(test_2 <- test_data %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(min_val = min(x:x3), max_val = max(x:x3)))
```

What I actually want to do is something like

```
mutate(min_val = min([,2:samples+1]), max_val = max([,2:samples+1])))
```

because (1) I wish to retain the id column (for later joining with another data frame), and (2) specifying by column position seems an obvious way of doing this as I am unconcerned with the column name and samples may be large.

Thank you!

**Edited example**

This (as suggested)

```
test_data %>%
  nest(-id) %>%                         # nest rest of columns apart from id
  mutate(min_val = map(data, min),      # get min and max
         max_val = map(data, max)) %>%
  unnest()
```

works on the original test data. However, the real-world data has repetitions of id, e.g.

```
(test_data <- tibble(id = c(1:9, 1:9), 
                     x = runif(18), 
                     x2 = runif(18),
                     x3 = runif(18)))
```

and this results in 'Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.'.

Answer (score 3):

A possible `tidyverse` solution is to `nest` any columns you have, apart from `id`, and then use `map` to get `min` and `max`. You won't need to specify any column names:

```
library(tidyverse)

# test data
(test_data <- tibble(id = c(1:9), 
                     x = runif(9), 
                     x2 = runif(9),
                     x3 = runif(9)))
samples = 100    

test_data %>%
  nest(-id) %>%                         # nest rest of columns apart from id
  mutate(min_val = map(data, min),      # get min and max
         max_val = map(data, max)) %>%
  unnest()                              # unnest columns

# # A tibble: 9 x 6
#      id min_val max_val      x     x2    x3
#   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  0.0217   0.239 0.130  0.0217 0.239
# 2     2  0.125    0.814 0.625  0.814  0.125
# 3     3  0.281    0.770 0.331  0.770  0.281
# 4     4  0.123    0.868 0.123  0.644  0.868
# 5     5  0.149    0.340 0.149  0.340  0.337
# 6     6  0.496    0.865 0.596  0.865  0.496
# 7     7  0.0766   0.984 0.0766 0.656  0.984
# 8     8  0.272    0.926 0.702  0.926  0.272
# 9     9  0.433    0.912 0.912  0.433  0.590
```

In the case of having multiple ids you can use this:

```
test_data %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%     # create a row identifier
  nest(-id, -row_id) %>%                # nest rest of columns apart from id and row id
  mutate(min_val = map(data, min),      # get min and max
         max_val = map(data, max)) %>%
  unnest()                              # unnest columns
```

Comment: Note, that you don't need to call `group_by()`. Just use `nest(-id)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm used to `group_by` and `nest`, but will change that from now on :)

Comment: Than you for not only answering the question but for showing me how map can be used in this case (I had been trying to use it to obtain the row-wise min and max, feeling it would be a better way, but had not succeeded). This example works perfectly on the test day. On my real-world data set, however, I receive 'Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements'. This appears to be because the id columns has repeated values of id (I have edited the original question appropriately). Thank you

Comment: You can assign a unique ID to all rows by `df <- tibble::rowid_to_column(df, "id_uni")`

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm using `row_number` to create a unique id, but `rowid_to_column` is really good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `pmin/pmax`

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data %>% 
     mutate(min_val = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1])),
            max_val = pmax(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1])))
# A tibble: 9 x 6
#     id     x     x2     x3 min_val max_val
#  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 0.293 0.255  0.501   0.255    0.501
#2     2 0.225 0.605  0.139   0.139    0.605
#3     3 0.704 0.371  0.0939  0.0939   0.704
#4     4 0.519 0.672  0.552   0.519    0.672
#5     5 0.663 0.673  0.725   0.663    0.725
#6     6 0.920 0.320  0.138   0.138    0.920
#7     7 0.280 0.904  0.223   0.223    0.904
#8     8 0.764 0.198  0.688   0.198    0.764
#9     9 0.802 0.0442 0.0765  0.0442   0.802
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
test_data <- tibble(id = c(1:9), 
                    x = runif(9), 
                    x2 = runif(9),
                    x3 = runif(9))
```

Comment: Thank you: this does the trick. It also does the trick with id = c(1:9, 1_9), i.e. with an id variable that repeats, which is what I need! It also works with my real data (>100,000 rows). I confess, however that I do not undertstand the syntax 'min_val = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1]))'!

Comment: @Martino  The `names(.)[-1]` gives the column names of the dataset except the first column  name as  a string.  It is converted to `symbol` with `syms` and then evaluate (`!!!`) to get the values of those column on which `pmin` or `pmax` is applied for row wise min or max.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation (which I understand at least in part!) - I will study this further.